# Entity Framework Core - Failed migration with Npgsql provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am having an error when trying to create a database from its model using Entity Framework Core 2.0.1 and the provider npgsql 2.0.1.

The error description is:

"constraint «FK_PiezasStockExterno_ContenedoresDocumentos_IdContenedorDocume» for relation «PiezasStockExterno» already exists".

I have no call to Database.EnsureCreated() since I'm aware it causes troubles while migrating, and the database is being dropped before so I ensure it doesn't exist. It happens either using the below commands or calling that Database.EnsureCreated(). What could be the real issue?

Error script:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."PiezasStockExterno" 
(    
"Id" serial NOT NULL,   
"IdContenedorDocumentosPieza" int4 NULL,    
"IdContenedorDocumentosVehiculo" int4 NULL,

CONSTRAINT "PK_PiezasStockExterno" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),    
CONSTRAINT "FK_PiezasStockExterno_ContenedoresDocumentos_IdContenedorDocumentosPieza" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("IdContenedorDocumentosPieza") 
    REFERENCES "public"."ContenedoresDocumentos" ("Id") ON DELETE RESTRICT,    
CONSTRAINT "FK_PiezasStockExterno_ContenedoresDocumentos_IdContenedorDocumentosVehiculo" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("IdContenedorDocumentosVehiculo") 
    REFERENCES "public"."ContenedoresDocumentos" ("Id") ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

Models:

```
[Table("PiezasStockExterno", Schema = "public")]
public class PiezaStockExterno
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? IdContenedorDocumentosPieza { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdContenedorDocumentosPieza")]
    public virtual ContenedorDocumentos ContenedorDocumentosPieza { get; set; }

    public int? IdContenedorDocumentosVehiculo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdContenedorDocumentosVehiculo")]
    public virtual ContenedorDocumentos ContenedorDocumentosVehiculo { get; set; }

}

[Table("ContenedoresDocumentos", Schema = "public")]
public class ContenedorDocumentos
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ContenedorDocumentos")]
    public IList<Imagen> Imagenes { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ContenedorDocumentos")]
    public IList<Foto> Fotos { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ContenedorDocumentos")]
    public IList<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ContenedorDocumentos")]
    public IList<Video> Videos { get; set; }

}
```

Context:

```
public NContext(DbContextOptions<NContext> options) : base(options)
{

}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(ConnectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("WebAPI"));
    optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

Startup.cs in WebAPI project:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<Infrastructure.Data.NContext>();       

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()) 
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

    AutoMapperConfig.Initialize();
}
```

Commands:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
dotnet ef database update

OR

Database.EnsureCreated()
```

InitialMigration.cs:

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "PiezasStockExterno",
            schema: "public",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn),                    
                IdContenedorDocumentosPieza = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                IdContenedorDocumentosVehiculo = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)                    
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_PiezasStockExterno", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_PiezasStockExterno_ContenedoresDocumentos_IdContenedorDocumentosPieza",
                    column: x => x.IdContenedorDocumentosPieza,
                    principalSchema: "public",
                    principalTable: "ContenedoresDocumentos",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_PiezasStockExterno_ContenedoresDocumentos_IdContenedorDocumentosVehiculo",
                    column: x => x.IdContenedorDocumentosVehiculo,
                    principalSchema: "public",
                    principalTable: "ContenedoresDocumentos",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely are hitting the [PostgreSQL Max Identifier Length of 63 bytes](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/8f87c65a0a-postgresqls-max-identifier-length-is-63-bytes) with the FK constraint names, which after truncation become one and the same, hence the confusing *already exist* error (although it can be seen that the name is truncated).

Since specifying FK constraint name currently is possible [only with Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/fk-constraints), you need to override `OnModelCreating` and add the following code (use any names that make sense to you and don't exceed 63 characters):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PiezaStockExterno>()
    .HasOne(e => e.ContenedorDocumentosPieza)
    .WithMany()
    .HasConstraintName("FK_PiezasStockExterno_IdContenedorDocumentosPieza");

modelBuilder.Entity<PiezaStockExterno>()
    .HasOne(e => e.ContenedorDocumentosVehiculo)
    .WithMany()
    .HasConstraintName("FK_PiezasStockExterno_IdContenedorDocumentosVehiculo");
```

And in case you add inverse collection navigation properties, don't forget to update the corresponding `WithMany` call.

Comment: That was it! I was stuck for hours. Thank you.